# jQuery UI: Add widget depending on class not on id

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, jquery-ui

I'm new to Apache Cordova and jQueryUI. I'm just trying out to format the layout of my index.html by jQueryUI.

According to [This section of the jQueryUI tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/#basic-overview-using-jquery-ui-on-a-web-page) a widget is added by the following two code snippets:

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="date">
```

(in HTML) and

```
$( "#date" ).datepicker();
```

(in a `<script>` tag in the header). This example adds the datepicker-widget for all html elements with **ID = date**.

My question now is, whether it is possible to add a widget for **elements of a specific html class (or something like that) instead by their ids**. I need different id's for my elements because i get them by Cordova's document.getElementById() method.

Here my example code:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>MyApp</title>

  <link href="jqueryui/css/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="jqueryui/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="jqueryui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>

  <script>
    // # = ID / . = Klasse
    $("#datepicket").datepicker();  // Works, widget is added for ID

    $(".button").button();          // Add widget by class WON'T WORK!
    $("#myBtn").button();           // Add widget by ID is OK - WORKS!
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="myBtn" class="button">
    My button
  </button>
...
```

Like explained above, the ui formating works if i use the id selector "#myBtn" but wont work when class selector ".button" is used.

Someone an idea how to avoid this same-id problem (I also don't like to add a widget setting for each different id (for each button id one script-line))? Thank you!

***************** **EDIT - FOLLOWING CODE WORKS** **********************

```
...
  <script>
     // THIS function declaration I've forgotten!!!
     $(function () {
        $(".button").button();  // # = ID / . = Klasse
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    });
  </script>
...
```

Comment: Assign same Class name e.g. class="somename" to all html elements you want Datepicker widget enabled on and try $(".somename").datepicker();

Comment: Ah I got it working now, thank you for your clue!!! My mistake was that I didn't add the widget calls to a new function. Everything works fine, I adapted the code above! Thank you!

Comment: Also you can have same name/class for multiple HTML elements but not ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $(".button").each(function() {
      $(this).button();
   });
});
```

Comment: This function did it for my! I added the $(".button").each... logic to the onDeviceReady() function of my Cordova app and it worked!